# How to generate a sample in R or which the distance between the numbers drawn is equal

Tags: r, seq

I am working in R and I am trying to generate a sample of N, but the distance between all the numbers must be equal. So for example a set of 5 numbers out of 1:10 between which the distance of each number is 2 would give (c(1,3,5,7,9).

Right now I have `runif(N, min = 0, max = 10)`, but this will give me just N numbers randomly. The same happens when I use the sample function.

I have been trying to figure this out for the past day but could not find a thread/function with a solution. Does someone have a clue?

Comment: It sounds like you want to procedurally (not randomly) generate the set of numbers. To do that you would want to use `seq`. Then you could randomly shuffle them using `sample`

Comment: Thanks! this works

Comment: but the problem here is that when you then draw a sample from the seq, the distance between the numbers is still not equal

Comment: Well if you use sample to just shuffle then the distance between the ordered values in the same.  The main issue you're going to find with getting help is that your problem is either not defined well enough for us (so just give more examples with example input/output) or it's just not well defined in general.

Comment: And actually reading your comment on the now deleted answer makes it seem like the issue is that you haven't read into the parameters of seq well enough.  There is an option for you to defined the start/stop values AND just tell it out how many values you want in total (so you don't need to specify the actual gap itself).  There is no randomness in this though so you need to pay better attention to when you talk about randomness and/or taking a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myfun <- function(R, N, I) {
              max.start <- tail(range,1)-(N-1)*2 # sequence of output cannot extend beyond range
              start <- sample(max.start, 1)
              seq(start, by=I, length.out=N)
         }

range <- 1:10
N <- 5
interval <- 2

# 1 trial
myfun(range, N, interval)
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10

# 10 trials
t(replicate(10, myfun(range, N, interval)))
      # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 # [1,]    1    3    5    7    9
 # [2,]    1    3    5    7    9
 # [3,]    2    4    6    8   10
 # [4,]    1    3    5    7    9
 # [5,]    1    3    5    7    9
 # [6,]    2    4    6    8   10
 # [7,]    2    4    6    8   10
 # [8,]    2    4    6    8   10
 # [9,]    1    3    5    7    9
# [10,]    2    4    6    8   10
```